# Classpath file not visible in eclipse, on mac system?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I have a mac machine, I created a spring project - it builds and run perfectly fine. But I am not able to see or find .classpath it generates in eclipse. How can view that?

In windows if I do same, I can easily see the file on windows machine.

Any solutions?

Comment: How are you trying to “see” and “find” it?

Comment: On Windows, you may be viewing your workspace in the Navigator view, rather than an explorer view. So, open Window>Show View>Other>General>Navigator or use the solution given by Till Brychcy

Answer (score 2):

In the eclipse package explorer, click on the little triangle pointing down to reveal the view menu, choose "Filters..." and deselect ".*"-resources.

In the macOS Finder, click Command-Shift-. to toggle displaying the hidden files (on macOS Sierra or later)